# Nesting form in admin-on-rest not working

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I am new using `admin-on-rest` framework, I need to make nested form working.

I have two models show and song.show() can have multiple songs. I have show edit form it will work as expected.

I need to add a song form inside show edit form, so I can add multiple songs for each show.

I tried all ways but i am not able to get it done.

This is my code:

```
<Edit title="Edit Show" {...this.props}>
    <SimpleField>
        <TextInput source="name" style={{ display: 'inline-block' }} />
       //here need to add song add form without reloading page
       //this is songs grid
           <ReferenceManyField reference="songs" target="show_id" label="Set List" perPage={5} >
               <Datagrid>
                   <TextField source="song_name" />
                   <EditButton />
                   <DeleteButton />
               </Datagrid>
           </ReferenceManyField>
       //Here need to add song form, so i can add songs
   </SimpleField>
</Edit>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should show the exact problem you are having. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Changed question to improve quality

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that answers your question.. if songs pre-exist then you just need to do that:

```
<Edit title="Edit Show" {...this.props}>
       <TextInput source="name" style={{ display: 'inline-block' }} />
       <ReferenceArrayInput label="Songs" source="songs_property_on_show" reference="songs" allowEmpty>
            <SelectArrayInput optionText="song_name" translate={false}/>
       </ReferenceArrayInput>
</Edit>
```

if you want to create them on the fly while you are creating the show or in other words have a form inside the other this needs to be done in a custom way (using redux-form) as commented under my question: [how to create an entity inside another in the same form using admin-on-rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918638/how-to-create-an-entity-inside-another-in-the-same-form-using-admin-on-rest)